# Chrome throwing Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected Number - php, javascript

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome

```
<?php 
        $key = fopen("auctions/key.txt", 'r');
        $name = Array();
        $date = Array();
        $a = 0;
        echo '<script>time = {};</script>';
        while (!feof($key))
        {
            array_push($name, fgets($key));
            array_push($date, fgets($key));

            fgets($key); //skip the blank line
            $a_date = $date[$a];
            echo 
            "<script>
                var a = $a_date;
                time.push(a); 

            </script>"; 
            $a++;
        }
        fclose($key);

    ?>
```

The purpose of this code is to assign some javascript information to be used later based on a file that is saved in the server's files (key.txt). However, when I echo out the  to set the variables, (specifically at `var a = $a_date`) Chrome says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number. What is causing this? I do know it is the `var a = $a_date` part, as when I comment it out, the error is not thrown.

Comment: What is the script you're getting?

Comment: I'm not 'getting' a script. All of the javascript is visible here, it is echoed out. I assume that's what you mean, anyway.

Comment: What is it echoing for`$a_date`?

Comment: The proper thing written in the file `key.txt`

Comment: For what it's worth, this code is going to fail and could be much simpler. `time = {}` creates a global *object* in JS, not an array. To make an array you do this: `var time = []`. Also, it's a really bad idea to make a whole bunch of script tags for each item in the array. Instead, you should just generate your array in PHP then do `echo "var time = " . json_encode($myArray) . ";"`.